# Insert into when username matches

Tags: postgresql

Suppose my table user_info has 2 columns, one is #username and another one is #info.

Now I already made a query "INSERT INTO user_info(username) value('')

How can I make another query to put data on column #info for the same username?? Because after the first query I'll have null for the column #info I believe.

Just to clarify, I don't get the #info when I have the username. Each user will get their info later. So I can't put then on the same query.

Comment: You can specify multiple columns, and multiple values; e.g.: `INSERT INTO user_info (username, info) VALUES ('some username', 'some info');`

Comment: I don't get the info's when i get the username.

Comment: You probably need an update statement then: `UPDATE user_info SET info='value' WHERE username='existingname'`

Comment: You don't INSERT to add information to an existing row. You use UPDATE. You should find a good SQL tutorial or video to learn the basics before you begin trying to work with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you need to update the row, simply using update on where the username exist

From documentation:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1,
    column2 = value2,
    ...
WHERE condition;
```

Your case:

```
UPDATE user_info 
SET info='new_information' 
WHERE username='existing_username'
```